# Синтаксический разбор предложения, 7 класс

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Мне нужно подписать характеристику, члены предложения я подчеркнул, части речи подписал, а вот с характеристикой встал в ступор (пов., невоскл., прост., двусост., распр., не осл.?) Не знаю, правильно ли. Вот само предложение:

*В палатке мы увидели не разбросанные, а аккуратно сложенные рюкзаки.*

Answer (score 2):

*В палатке мы увидели **не разбросанные, а аккуратно сложенные** рюкзаки.*

В чём ступор? Если есть знаки препинания внутри предложения - есть и осложнение. Здесь запятая разделяет однородные определения: увидели (что?) рюкзаки (какие?) не разбросанные, а аккуратно сложенные.

Предложение осложнено однородными определениями, выраженными одиночным причастием и необособленным причастным оборотом.